# special character in a phrase even though enclosed by "quotation marks" generates error

Tags: linux, elasticsearch

I have the following code:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/INDEXED REPOSITORY/_search -d '{"query": {"constant_score": {"filter" : {"terms" : {"description" : ["adam attack stokes","adam stokes attacks","adam-stokes attacks","adam-stokes syndrome","adams attack stoke","adams stoke syndrome","adams stokes attack","adams stokes syndrome","adams-stokes","adams-stokes syndrome","adams-stokes; attack","attack; adams-stokes","attack; stokes-adams","attacks adam-stokes","attacks stokes-adams","morgagni\s disease","morgagni-adam\s stokes syndrome","morgagni-stokes-adams","spens\ syndrome","stoke adams syndrome","stokes adams attack","stokes adams attacks","stokes adams syndrome","stokes-adams","stokes-adams attack","stokes-adams attacks","stokes-adams syndrome","stokes-adams-morgagni syndrome","stokes-adams; attack","syndrome adams-stokes","syndrome stokes-adams","syndrome adams-stokes","syndrome stokes-adams","3-12 anginal syndromes","angina","angina of effort","angina pain","angina pectoris","angina syndrome","angina cardiac","anginal discomfort","anginal pain","anginal syndrome","anginal syndromes","anginal; syndrome","anginas","angor pectoris","ap - angina pectoris","cardiac angina","cardio/pulm: angina","chest pain - cardiac","chest pain ischemic","chest; pain ischemic","ischaemic chest pain","ischaemic heart disease - angina","ischaemic ht dis - angina","ischemic chest pain","ischemic heart disease - angina","ischemic ht dis - angina","pain angina","pain; chest ischemic","pectoris angina","stenocardia","stenocardias","syndrome; anginal","angina pectoris variant","angina pectoris; variant","angina prinzmetal","angina variant","angina variant <prinzmetal>","angina variant prinzmetal","angina prinzmetal","angina prinzmetal\s","coronary artery spasm angina","prinzmetal angina","prinzmetal variant angina","prinzmetal\s angina","prinzmetal; angina","prinzmetals angina","variant angina","variant angina pectoris","variant; angina","vasospastic angina","angina at rest","angina pectori unstable","angina pectoris unstable","angina pectoris unstable","angina pectoris; at rest","angina pectoris; crescendo","angina pectoris; unstable","angina unstable","angina preinfarction","angina unstable","anginal chest pain at rest","anginas preinfarction","anginas unstable","coronary; syndrome","crescendo angina","crescendo angina pectoris","crescendo; angina","impending infarction","intermed coronary synd","intermediate coronary syndrome","intermediate coronary; syndrome","myocardial ischemia impending infarction","pre-infarction syndrome","preinfarction angina","preinfarction anginas","preinfarctional; angina","rest angina","rest; angina","syndrome; coronary","syndrome; intermediate coronary","unstable angina","unstable angina pectori","unstable angina pectoris","unstable anginas","unstable; angina","worsening angina","aortic stenosis supra valvular","aortic stenosis supravalv","aortic stenosis supravalvar","aortic stenosis supravalvular","aortic supravalv stenosis","aortic supravalvular stenoses","aortic supravalvular stenosis","stenoses aortic supravalvular","stenosis aortic supravalvular","stenosis supravalvular aortic","supra-aortic stenosis","supra-valvular aortic stenosis","supravalv aortic stenosis","supravalvar aortic stenosis","supravalvular aorta constricted","supravalvular aortic stenosis","supravalvular stenoses aortic","supravalvular stenosis aortic","svas","svas - supravalvar aortic stenosis","ai - aortic incompetence","aorta; incompetency","aorta; insufficiency","aortic (valve) insufficiency","aortic incompetence","aortic insufficiency","aortic regurgitation","aortic valve incompetence","aortic valve insufficiency","aortic valve regurgitation","aortic valve incompetence","aortic valve insufficiency","aortic valve regurgitation","aortic valve; incompetency","aortic valve; insufficiency","aortic valve; regurgitation","ar - aortic regurgitation","incompetence aortic","incompetence aortic valve","incompetency; aortic valve","insufficiency aortic valve","insufficiency; aortic","regurgitation aortic","r"]}}}}}'
```

My goal was to get the number of unique records that include any of these keywords. With 2, 3 keywords it was working fine. 
But with this list of keywords, first I saw this error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `valve'
```

Then, I saw this error:

```
{"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[6hWIW7xlSbSqKi4dNg_1bg][INDEXED REPOSITORY][0]: SearchParseException[[INDEXED REPOSITORY][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source ......
```

Also, I have to mention that the format of the keywords has been changed to :

```
 .....\"angina pectoris; crescendo\",\"angina pectoris; unstable\",\"angina unstable\",\"angina preinfarction\",\"angina unstable\",\"anginal chest pain at rest\",\"anginas preinfarction\",\"anginas unstable\",\"coronary; syndrome\",\"crescendo angina\",\"crescendo angina pectoris\",\"crescendo; angina\"
```

Is it because of special characters like semi colon in "aortic valve; incompetency"? But I want to be able to do insensitive, exact match search. 
Any idea why it is happening?
I REALLY appreciate your help.

Comment: You might be better moving that JSON into a file and using the [`-d @data.json` option](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d). This will also stop `bash` trying to escape things.

Comment: The problem comes from `morgagni\s disease` you need to escape the backslashes properly in your terms.

Comment: Thanks @Ken Y-N. Can you please direct me to some online training regarding this? I started learning elasticsearch 2 weeks ago!

Comment: Thanks @Val. What should I do if I need to keep the format as it is?

Comment: I don't think any training is necessary! Just copy the JSON into a file, and perhaps use a [JSON validator](https://jsonlint.com/) to confirm your syntax is correct.

Comment: You just need to write `morgagni\\s disease` instead of `morgagni\s disease` or remove all backslashes like this `morgagnis disease`

Comment: @Val thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The credit goes to @Val. He said:The problem comes from morgagni\s disease you need to escape the backslashes properly in your terms.